# Extracting Data from Multiple Tables for sales vs expenditure

Tags: sql

I have three tables and i want create a report on it the structure of the data is as follows

Table A

```
CODE DESCRIPTION
001  CATS
```

Table B

```
CODE DESCRIPTION Amount TABLEACODE
0001 food        400          001  
0001 docter      500          001
```

Table C

```
CODE DESCRIPTION Amount TABLEACODE
0001 Sales       100          001  
0001 Sales       600          001
```

I have used the following script but it dose not provide accurate result

```
Select
Table A.code,
Table A.Description,
SUM(TableB.Amount)
SUM(Tablec.Amount) 
From
Table A
inner join table b on
TableA.code = TableB.TABLEACODE
inner join table c on
TableA.code = TableC.TABLEACODE
Group by
Table A.code,
Table A.Description
```

But the results don't match

I want the resultant report to be as follows

```
CODE DESCRIPTION SUM(TableB.Amount) SUM(Tablec.Amount)

001  Cats           900                  700
```

I would be obliged for your help

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lateral join` :

```
select a.code, a.decription, b.amount as b_amount, c.amount as c_amount
from tablea a cross apply
     ( select sum(b.amount) as amount
       from tableb b
       where b.TABLEACODE = a.code  
     ) b cross apply
     ( select sum(c.amount) as amount
       from tablec c
       where c.TABLEACODE = a.code  
     ) c;
```

This `lateral join` available in SQL Server, but different database has own syntax.

Comment: i have oracle data base and i am using oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get a Cartesian product when you `JOIN` all three tables together.  You can see this, if you don't aggregate the results but just look at all the rows returned.

One method uses correlated subqueries:

```
select a.code, a.decription, 
       ( select sum(b.amount) as amount
         from tableb b
         where b.TABLEACODE = a.code  
       ) b_amount,
       ( select sum(c.amount) as amount
         from tablec c
         where c.TABLEACODE = a.code  
       ) c_amount
from tablea a;
```